# How to fire an ajax request in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have service defined in Angular 2 like this:

```
import { Inject } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { Http ,Headers , HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';

export interface CourseInterface {
    courseId: number,
    coursePrice: number,
    authorName: string
}

export class CourseDetailsService {
    http: Http;
    constructor(@Inject(Http) Http) {
        console.log(Http)
        this.http = Http;
    }

    load() {
        console.log("came here in service")
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', <my username password>);

        this.http.get('https://some.api',{
            headers : headers
        }).map(res => console.log("Response came!!!"))

        console.log("done . . .")
    }
}
```

and in another component, I use this service like this:

```
import {CourseInterface, CourseDetailsService} from '../services/course';

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    viewBindings: [CourseDetailsService]
})
@View({
    template: `
        <h1>Dashboard page laoded</h1>
  `
})
export class Dashboard {
    constructor(service: CourseDetailsService) {
        service.load();
    }
}
```

and while running the application, I can see my `Dashboard` component gets displayed on the screen. But however from the `CourseDetailsService`, no http calls are getting fired.

But in the console I could able to see the following printed:

```
came here in service
done . . . .
```

But in my chrome networks tab, I couldn't able to see any request fired to the specified url. Where I am making mistake?

I'm using Angular 2 Alpha 47

Comment: The part that triggers the request it is the `subscribe`. So do `return this.http.get().map()`, and then in your component do `service.load().subscribe((result) => ...)`.

Comment: @EricMartinez: So it basically returns an `Observable`? To which I need to subscribe and get my streams?

Comment: @Ants You are absolutely right! :D

Comment: @EricMartinez: Thanks, was confused with this. You can give answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically the part that triggers the request itself it's the `subscribe`, so to make it work you have to add it.

```js
// Service
load() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', <my username password>);

    return this.http.get('https://some.api',{
        headers : headers
    }).map(res => console.log("Response came!!!"))
}

// Component
// 'subscribe' triggers the request!
service.load().subscribe((result) => /* do something with result */);
```

Comment: :Totally out of this question, if say I have an array of unique request, like `/something`,`/other`, in those cases, how can I return the observables so that the consumer can capture them?

Comment: My approach would be to create separate methods like : `loadSomething`, `loadOther`, where the first case would do a request to `https://some.api/something`. The rest would look like the answer : `service.loadSomething().subscribe(...)`. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Another approach : add a parameter to `load()`, like `load(query) { return http.get(query).subscribe(...)}`. This approach is better than the above one.

Comment: Thanks, I was too thinking the same approach.

Comment: can this approach make synchronous calls ? For example I need the server to validate the user rights for accessing a page and I would like this call to be synchronous and not add an *ngIf to not show the view until the call ends, I don't want to make a normal ajax request if I can use the http service

Comment: Why they made something such a simple and basic thing so complicated.