# Is there any method to connect HBase REST API with ionic app?

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, ionic2, hbase

Several days ago i left a question is for a method to connect HBase with ionic app. A good guy give me a nice solution that is to use REST API. HBase provides REST API so i try to use it with `curl` command on terminal. But the actual problem is that I have to use them on ionic app. I'm a new for ionic and REST so i cannot find a good resources.

Is there any method to connect HBase REST API with ionic app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your query:

1. Using REST API provided by HBase you want to do CRUD operations on your data
2. You are able to simulate these operations using cli (curl) on your terminal. Thus you must be having your own (or hosted) HBase server.
   Hence you are aware of the events on which you want to call a specific API with specific set of data (in form of http GET or POST request)

So it is matter of calling your api from ionic2 app.

Here is a [reference](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/) of blog on how to do REST call to your server.

All you have to do is for a http event subscribe for response which will be returned by your HBase server

I would suggest you to build a provider (service) to handle all your HBase server calls. Read [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/) for more details on how to create a service

Answer (score 1):

Under the fallowing link of Ionic Docs [Ionic Concepts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/concepts/)

***Angular is the underlying framework that powers Ionic. It is responsible for the component API that is the building block of Ionic. For an overview on Angular, be sure to checkout the official Angular Docs or checkout Learn Angular 2, which is maintained by the Ionic Team.***

Right now Angular 4.0 is released So Angular 2 is maintained by Ionic group fallow this link to read more on Angular 2

[Angular 2 ref](http://learnangular2.com/)

So angular 2 ajax calls should work in ionic. refer these links

[ajax call in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104221/how-to-fire-an-ajax-request-in-angular-2)

you can google to find more refrence